# Adding toolbars to a view

Tags: iphone

What kind of toolbars are these at the top and bottom of the view?

[image]

How are these added in the code rather than in IB?

Answer (score 2):

The top portion looks like a `UINavigationController` presented modally from another `UIViewController`.  The cancel button is added in the

`- (void)viewDidLoad` method of the view as the right navigation item.

The bottom is just a plain old `UIToolBar` with 4 buttons.

All `UINavigationControllers` have a `UIToolbar` built in and it's just a matter of calling the following function to display it.

```
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO];
```

If you want to create buttons, you can call...

```
- (void)setToolbarItems:(NSArray *)toolbarItems animated:(BOOL)animated
```

to configure `UIToolbar` items.  All the items in a `UIToolbar` are just an `NSArray` of objects.  In this case your objects are buttons.  In order to properly space the items in the `UIToolbar` there's a flexible space object that you can put between your buttons to make it look pretty.  So when you setup your array of toolbar items you'd have.  Button | Space | Button | Space | Button | Space | Button to accomplish the above look.

Here's some info on the [UIToolbar Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIToolbar_Class/Reference/Reference.html) if you get lost.